# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection??

Tags: c#, indexing, nunit

im doing this simple for and i get this error. When i change TRUE to FALSE it doesnt give that error, but the test real error... but i need the test to pass and i dont understand.. can anybody help? C# visual studio 2010 NUnit

```
[Test]

public void prueba1()
{

    List<int> lista1 = new List<int>();

    lista1.Add(1);

    lista1.Add(2);

    lista1.Add(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < lista1.Count; i++)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(lista1[i]);
        Assert.True(lista1[i]<lista1[i+1]);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The valid indexes into your list are 0 through 2.`lista1.Count` will be 3, so `i` goes from 0 to 2. When `i` is 2, you try to access `lista1[i+1]`, which is out of range.

Answer (score 2):

Your list is [1,2,3]

In each iteration, the following statements are being checked.
1 < 2
2 < 3
3 < ?

In Assert.True and Assert.False, an AssertFailedException error will be throw if the conditional being checked is not the same as the function call.(Assert.True needs True)

Assert.True(1 < 2) is valid,
Assert.True(2 < 3) is valid,
Assert.True(3 < ?) - An Out Of Bounds Exception will occur.

Assert.False(1 < 2) - An AssertFailedException will occur.

Answer (score 0):

`i+1` is the place of error. Change it. Why?

Your indexes should start from 0 and go till 2 but error comes in the last index because it tries to search for `i + 1` index which means it is searching for `lista1[3]` which does not exist as indexes start from 0 and go till 1 less than the length of collection.